# Как реализовать перелистывание списка в aiogram с помощью inline кнопок?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

На входе бот отправляет сообщение со списком вопросов, но если их много то возникает проблема чтения. Как сделать так чтобы пользователь мог листать список ? И как хранить этот большой список ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь сделать список и при помощи ниже приведенных способов переключать при помощи id

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prev")
async def prev_page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        await call.answer()
        data = int(call.data.split(":")[1]) - 1

        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
            InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:{data}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(str(data), callback_data="null"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:{data}"),
        )
    

        news_dict = news_dict[:6]
        await call.message.edit_text(news_dict[data], reply_markup=markup)
    except:
        pass

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="next")
async def next_page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    data = int(call.data.split(":")[1]) + 1
    with open("all_posts.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:{data}"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(str(data), callback_data="null"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:{data}"),
    )
    await call.message.edit_text(news_dict[data], reply_markup=markup)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Список"))
async def get_5_news(message: types.Message):
    with open("all_posts.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                        InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:0"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("0", callback_data="null"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:1")
                    )
        await message.answer('text', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]